# Reading n bytes atomically without blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, stream, inputstream

I just asked a question about why my thread shut down wasn't working. It ended up being due to `readLine()` blocking my thread before the shutdown flag could be recognised. This was easy to fix by checking `ready()` before calling `readLine()`.

However, I'm now using a `DataInputStream` to do the following in series:

```
int x = reader.readInt();
int y = reader.readInt();
byte[] z = new byte[y]
reader.readFully(z);
```

I know I could implement my own buffering which would check the running file flag while loading up the buffer. But I know this would be tedious. Instead, I could let the data be buffered within the `InputStream` class, and wait until I have my `n` bytes read, before executing a non-blocking read - as I know how much I need to read.

- `4` bytes for the first integer
- `4` bytes for the second integer `y`
- and `y` bytes for the `z` byte array.

Instead of using `ready()` to check if there is a line in the buffer, is there some equivalent `ready(int bytesNeeded)`?

Comment: [It seems there's a `read() method that accepts a number of bytes to read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)), will that work?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy No, it returns an int, which is the number of bytes actually read. This will require me to implement some buffering.

Answer (score 0):

The `available()` method returns the amount of bytes in the `InputStream`s internal buffer.

So, one can do something like:

```
while (reader.available() < 4) checkIfShutdown();
reader.readInt();
```

Comment: As I found out years ago, counting on InputStream.available is going to mess you up at some point down the road

Comment: For my type of stream, it works fine. I'll keep note that this doesn't universally work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InputStream.available()` to get an estimate of the amount of bytes that can be read. Quoting [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available()):

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking, which may be 0, or 0 when end of stream is detected. The read might be on the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

In other words, if `available()` returns `n`, you know you can safely call `read(n)` without blocking. Note that, as the Javadoc states, the value returned is an estimate. For example, [InflaterInputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html#available()) will always return 1 if EOF isn't reached. Check the documentation of the `InputStream` subclass you will be using to ensure it meets your needs.

Comment: See this about using available and GZIPInputStream: https://pzampino.github.io/2018/10/09/gzipinputstream-and-available.html

Comment: @ControlAltDel Good point, I added a mention of this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to implement your own equivalent of `BufferedInputStream`. Either as a sole owner of an `InputStream` and a thread (possibly borrowed from a pool) to block in. Alternatively, implement with NIO.

Comment: Would wrapping the stream in `BufferedInputStream` provide a reliable `available()` method

Comment: @Tobiq Well, no. It doesn't actively read from the underlying blocking stream. It will only do so reactively when it's out of bytes and then block itself.

Comment: So it simply sub-buffers your reads (an overall buffer is still needed incase the eof isn't reached yet, thus requires subsequent reads)?